# addEventListener works randomly and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript and I am trying to show different kinds of projects while pressing a button. The html button shows the html projects, the same with bootstrap button and wordpress button. The thing is the script works randomly. If I have 4 different projects only works if 2 of them are html projects. If I add more projects sometimes works sometimes doesn't work.

```
<div class="botones">
    <div class="todos">
        <p>TODOS</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ht">
        <p>HTML</p>
    </div>

    <div class="wp">
        <p>WORDPRESS</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bt">
        <p>BOOTSTRAP</p>
    </div>
</div>               

<div class="content-proyec">
    <div class="sample wp-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-cocinero.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample bt-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-woocommerce.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample bt-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-justicia.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample ht-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-jane.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var ht = document.querySelectorAll(".ht-pro");
    var wordpress = document.querySelectorAll(".wp-pro");
    var bootstrap = document.querySelectorAll(".bt-pro");
    var proyectos = document.querySelectorAll(".sample");


document.querySelectorAll(".botones div").forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (div.className == "todos"){
            for (var i = 0; i <= proyectos.length; i++){
                ht[i].style.display = "block";  
                wordpress[i].style.display = "block";           
                bootstrap[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        else if(div.className == "ht"){
            for (var i = 0; i <= proyectos.length; i++){
                ht[i].style.display = "block";
                wordpress[i].style.display = "none";                
                bootstrap[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        else if(div.className == "wp") {
            for (var i = 0; i <= proyectos.length; i++){
                ht[i].style.display = "none";
                wordpress[i].style.display = "block";                       
                bootstrap[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        else if(div.className == "bt") {
            for (var i = 0; i <= proyectos.length; i++){
                ht[i].style.display = "none";
                wordpress[i].style.display = "none";
                bootstrap[i].style.display = "block";           
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems like you have not added full `html` code. There is no element with class `botones `.

Comment: yes, i forgot, fixed

Answer (score 2):

The code to loop over all the divs to hide and show them is unmaintainable and redundant so as all the conditional statements, which quickly leads to spaghetti-code.

You could reduce a lot the javascript code needed, and use CSS to show/hide your blocks

```js
var btt = document.querySelector('.botones');
var cnt_proyec = document.querySelector('.content-proyec');

btt.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.matches('button')) {
    cnt_proyec.dataset['current'] = ev.target.className;
  }
})
```

```css
.sample {
  display: none;
}

[data-current="ht"] .ht-pro,
[data-current="wp"] .wp-pro,
[data-current="bt"] .bt-pro,
[data-current="todos"] .sample {
  display: block  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="botones">
  <button class="todos">
    TODOS
  </button>

  <button class="ht">
    HTML
  </button>

  <button class="wp">
    WORDPRESS
  </button>

  <button class="bt">
    BOOTSTRAP
  </button>
</div>



<div class="content-proyec">
    <div class="sample wp-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-cocinero.jpg" alt="wp-pro"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample bt-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-woocommerce.jpg" alt="bt-pro"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample bt-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-justicia.jpg" alt="bt-pro"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample ht-pro">
        <div class="sample-img">
            <a href=""><img src="img/proyectos/proyecto-jane.jpg" alt="ht-pro"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First, you should use real `<button>` elements instead of div (and style them as you prefer, of course) also for a matter of accessibility.

Then all you need is to capture a click event on the button wrapper element and detect the classname of the clicked button.

Use that class name as a `data-current` attribute on the proyec element and use that attribute to properly hide and show the blocks via CSS.